# Redirect from subdomain

Tags: redirect, tumblr

I'm moving a Tumblr site to WP and need to deal with a redirect. I'm using the [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/).

So, I need to redirect from http://blog.example.com > http://example.com

To achieve this, do I need to actually host the site at blog.example.com and redirect from there? Or do I need to setup a dummy site at blog.example.com?

Really have no idea how to tackle this at all. Suggestions very welcome!

Update:  Can this be achieved by adding a new vhost entry?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It simply redirect blog.example.com to example.com or blog.example.com?p=11 to example.com/?p=11.

[Source](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirect-subdomain-url-path-to-main-domain-and-keeping-exact-url-path).